# SELECT row if concatenated value contains text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

```
select dbo.strconcat(r.Name) as Names, r.Category
from Reference r
group by r.Category
```

For this query I need get categories which have at least one name (r.Name) LIKE any text.

Example:   condition  (LIKE '%123%')

123,2,4  - correct Names

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
;WITH A
     AS
        (SELECT dbo.strconcat
                (r.Name
                ) AS Names, r.Category
         FROM Reference r
         GROUP BY r.Category
        )
     SELECT *
     FROM A
     WHERE Names LIKE '%123%';
```

Comment: Yes, it's. I did that, but maybe there is not a better solution??

Comment: how about 

SELECT dbo.strconcat(r.Name) AS Names, r.Category 
FROM Reference r
WHERE dbo.strconcat(r.Name) LIKE '%123%'
GROUP BY r.Category

Comment: Not sure what the function dbo.strconcat() does but I guess from the name it concatenates a string with the column Name.

Comment: The other option would be to go with a Temp table.

Comment: yes, dbo.strconcat() concatenates a string with the column Name. But it's not full correct solution, because i insert ' ,' between Names. And LIKE '%,%' will not give me correct result.

Comment: Did "SELECT dbo.strconcat(r.Name) AS Names, r.Category FROM Reference r WHERE dbo.strconcat(r.Name) LIKE '%123%' GROUP BY r.Category" work?

Comment: "SELECT dbo.strconcat(r.Name) AS Names, r.Category FROM Reference r WHERE dbo.strconcat(r.Name) LIKE '%123%' GROUP BY r.Category" is not work. We must use HAVING there.